# Execute Javascript on a Azure ADB2C custom sign-up page

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-ad-b2c, custom-pages

I managed to be able to execute custom javascript on an Azure ADB2C sign-up page by using the "Custom page" feature and enabling Javascript from the User Flow properties in Azure ADB2C.

[image]

[image]

For example this works for making an alert appear when clicking on the "Continue" button when signing-up a new user:

```
document.getElementById("continue").onclick = () => alert('test');
```

However I would like my javascript to be executed only if the form is valid when clicking on the Continue button.

How can I execute a javascript function on the submit button of the sign-up form *only after  the form is validated successfully*?

Ref. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-user-flow

This is my custom page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Sign-up</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.4/css/bulma.min.css" data-preload="true">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.com/SignUp.css" data-preload="true">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.com/background.css" data-preload="true">
    <script defer src="https://example.com/SignUp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="bg">
        <div class="container pt-6">
            <div class="columns mt-6">
                <div class="column p-6 has-background-light">
                    <p class="block is-size-3">
                        Create your Free Account
                    </p>
                    <p class="block">
                        Blabla
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="column p-6 has-background-white">
                    <h3 class="title is-3">
                        Create your Account
                    </h3>
                    <div id="api" role="main">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```